# updating value not storing in database

Tags: database, vb.net, dataset

below code **working without ERRoR** but update value **not store in database**???
its a right method to update database value ???

```
Try

        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM studentdetails where student_id= @id", myConn)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txt_id.Text)
        da.Fill(dset, "studentdetails")

        If dset.Tables("studentdetails").Rows(0)("student_id") = Convert.ToInt32(txt_id.Text) Then
            dset.Tables("studentdetails").Rows(0)("student_name") = txt_name.Text
            dset.Tables("studentdetails").Rows(0)("student_branch") = txt_branch.Text
            dset.Tables("studentdetails").Rows(0)("student_class") = txt_class.Text
            MsgBox("Update Complete")
        Else
            MsgBox("Record not found")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally

        myConn.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: This code is for a SELECT not for an UPDATE. It doens't store anything

Comment: This code just *reads* data from db. To update you need something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store something in a database you need an INSERT command like this

```
Dim cmdInsert = "INSERT INTO studentdetails (student_id, student_name, " & _
                "student_branch, student_class) VALUES " & _
                "(@id, @name, @branch, @class)"
Dim cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdInsert,myConn) 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",Convert.ToInt32(txt_id.Text)(
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_name.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@branch", txt_branch.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", txt_class.Text)
Dim rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
if rowsInserted = 1 Then
   MsgBox("Record inserted")
Else
   MsgBox("Error inserting Record")
End If
```

Of course this tries to INSERT a new record in the database. To update an existing record you need an UPDATE command. Perhaps it is better to give a quick review at the [various SQL commands](http://w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Comment: As the DataAdapter is populated by a single table is it not possible just to Update it? `da.Update(dset)`

Comment: @AndyG Yes it is possible. It depends on the context but when working with textboxes instead of grids I prefer to work directly with the SqlCommand class

Comment: Thanks @Steve. I was reading that for a DataAdapter it requires the UpdateCommand to be specified, or the use of a CommandBuilder - a TableAdapter can perform the update (if a single table) without these being explicitly provided.

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need to select the record if you want to update it. Therefore i would use a `SqlCommand` with the appropriate update-sql. Then use it's `ExecuteNonQuery` method.

Second, since you are converting the ID to `Int32` i assume that the type of the column in the database is also `int`. But you are passing a `string` parameter to the `SelectCommand` of the `DataAdapter`. Note that `AddWithValue` tries to infer the type from the value, so you should provide the correct type.

However, if you want to use a `SqlDataAdapter` to update records you have to provide the `UpdateCommand`. Then all changes in  a DataTable/DataSet will be written to the database when you call `DataAdapter.Update`.

Here is an example (again, the select is redundant and inefficient since you could update directly with `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`):

```
Try
   Dim id As Int32
   If Not Int32.TryParse(txt_id.Text, id) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a valid ID!")
        Return
    End If

    Using myConn = New SqlConnection("Connection String")
        Using da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM studentdetails where student_id= @id", myConn)
            Dim table = New DataTable()
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
            da.Fill(table)
            If table.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                MsgBox("Record not found")
            Else
                da.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE studentdetails SET student_id=@student_id,student_name=@student_name,student_branch=@student_branch,student_class=@student_class WHERE student_id=@id", myConn)
                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_name", txt_name.Text)
                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_branch", txt_branch.Text)
                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_class", txt_class.Text)

                Dim row = table.Rows(0)
                row.SetField("student_id", Int32.Parse(txt_id.Text))
                row.SetField("student_name", txt_name.Text)
                row.SetField("student_branch", txt_branch.Text)
                row.SetField("student_class", txt_class.Text)

                da.Update(table)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    'You don't need to close the connection if you use the using-statement
    'myConn.Close()
End Try
```